# Spring JPA Repository - Operator SIMPLE_PROPERTY on jsonObject requires a scalar argument

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-types

I'm updating some Spring Boot Applications with JPA queries. Everything works fine except from one specific kind of queries (`findByJsonNode`). This worked fine in earlier versions, but after I upgraded my beans can't be created.

It worked fine up to Spring Boot `2.1.4.RELEASE` and spring cloud version `Greenwich.SR1`, but when I upgrade to Spring Boot `2.2.4.RELEASE` and spring cloud version `Hoxton.RELEASE`,  Spring can't create my repository bean.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operator SIMPLE_PROPERTY on searchDto requires a scalar argument, found class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode in method public abstract se.company.search.Search se.company.search.SearchRepository.findFirstBySearchDto(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode).
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.throwExceptionOnArgumentMismatch(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:171)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.validate(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:147)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:90)
    ... 73 common frames omitted.
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.throwExceptionOnArgumentMismatch(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:171) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.validate(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:147) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

The repository class  looks like below

```java
@Repository
public interface SearchRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Search, String> {

    Search findFirstBySearchDto(JsonNode searchDto);

}
```

Entity

```java
/**
 * Entity for saving as search
 *
 * Users can save searches and every search will be stored in history for reference
 */
@Slf4j
@Data
@Entity(name = "search")
@Table(name = "tt_searches", indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "searchDto", name = "searchdto_hidx")
})
@TypeDef(
        name = "json-node",
        typeClass = JsonNodeStringType.class
)
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "id", "savedSearches", "searchHistory" })
public class Search {

    public static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();

    public Search() {
    }

    public Search(SearchDto searchDto, List<SavedSearch> savedSearches, List<SearchHistory> searchHistory) {
        this.searchDto = OBJECT_MAPPER.valueToTree(searchDto);
        this.savedSearches = savedSearches;
        this.searchHistory = searchHistory;
    }

    public Search(JsonNode searchDto, List<SavedSearch> savedSearches, List<SearchHistory> searchHistory) {
        this.searchDto = searchDto;
        this.savedSearches = savedSearches;
        this.searchHistory = searchHistory;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Type(type = "json-node")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(2000)", unique = true)
    private JsonNode searchDto;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "search", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("name DESC")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<SavedSearch> savedSearches;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "search", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("timestamp DESC")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<SearchHistory> searchHistory;

    public SearchDto getSearchDto() {
        try {
            return OBJECT_MAPPER.treeToValue(searchDto, SearchDto.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Could not convert JsonNode to SearchDto when retrieving data from entity: {}", this.id);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setSearchDto(SearchDto searchDto) {
        this.searchDto = OBJECT_MAPPER.valueToTree(searchDto);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have now gotten the same error in another application when trying to update, but now when finding with the help of a `java.util.Set` as JPA query, like this `findAllByTags(java.util.Set)`

Comment: Not sure but have you  tried using `findByTagsIn` ?. You may have already seen this . https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1182 has added a validation to check method signatures for collection. There is also a bug report for issues with custom collections converters. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1682

Comment: Just to clarify, the issue states that you are passing a collection or multiple values to a parameter that expects single value. This might help someone in debugging, thanks

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I encountered this same problem. I worked around it by changing the name of my method by adding "In" to the end of it.

For your example, it would be

```
findAllByTagsIn(java.util.Set)
```

See the "supported keywords inside method names" table here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: This worked fine. And such a simple silly solution. Never thought about it since I was not using a collection but an object `JsonNode`. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

> > When you search entity by using list of column values as predicate, you must have to use "In" clause at the end of Column name. You can use inerrable

```
List<Entity> findAllByEntityColumnIn(Iterable<Long> EntityColumns);
```

Note: It is 100% tested on my project.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the repository and trying to get a list based on a parameter which is a type of Set you should be careful about writing queries! In my case:

```
findAllBySchoolId(Set<Long> schoolIds) // wrong
findAllBySchoolIdIn(Set<Long> schoolIds) // correct
```

Credits to user:8569305(smythie)!